# Eclipse Luna Quick Search Command

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The Quick Search Command seems to have disappeared in Luna. In Keplar, this was bound by default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. In Luna, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> brings up a list of the current key bindings which was the behavior prior to Keplar. I wouldn't mind binding Quick Search to another key combination, but it is not listed at all in the Keys preferences. Has this been deprecated? Is it available under a different command name?

Here is what Quick Search looked like in Keplar. The title on the window says "Quick Text Search", but the command in the Keys preference was "Quick Search Command".

[image: Eclipse quick search]

Comment: Could this be `Quick Search for Eclipse` in the Eclipse Marketplace (so not part of the standard install)?

Comment: Ah, I see it is from Spring Source. It was probably part of the Spring  STS, which was probably how I grabbed Keplar. This time I'm trying to keep Spring cleaner. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/eclipse-quick-search

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like it is `Quick Search for Eclipse` which is something you install from the Eclipse Marketplace.

So it will not be installed initially in a clean install of Luna.

Answer (score 4):

Try With This (For Windows PC):

**Ctrl+Alt+Shift** then press **L** key.

OR

**Ctrl+Shift** then press **L** key.